# Merge array based on same partner or letter

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have this nested array.

```
x = [
  [['A', 100], ['B', 200]], # ROW 1
  [['A', 150], ['C', 700]]  # ROW 2
].flatten(1)
```

I want to group these array based on the letters. So the output would be like this:

```
[
  ['A', 100, 150],
  ['B', 200, 0],
  ['C', 0, 700]
]
```

Here is my current code:

```
m = x.map(&:first).uniq.sort.map do |c|
  [c, x.select{|v| v.first == c}.map{|h| h.last}].flatten
end
```

Which returns:

```
[
  ['A', 100, 150], 
  ['B', 200], 
  ['C', 700]
]
```

So far this is as close as I can get. The problem with my output is that it doesn't add `0` if it does not exist in the row.

In `ROW 1`, `C` does not exist so I need to add `0` in the first column, same with `ROW 2`, `B` doesn't exist so I need to add `0` in the second column.

Comment: Regarding that `flatten(1)` – is the original array already flattened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two parts to your issue. First you need to know what 'keys' you are looking for. So `A, B, C`. If these are static, make them static, if not simply fetch them by doing:

```rb
x = [
  [['A', 100], ['B', 200]], # ROW 1
  [['A', 150], ['C', 700]]  # ROW 2
]

keys = x.flat_map{|l| l.map(&:first) }.uniq
```

Now the next part is finding out which keys are in which row. So that would become something like:

```rb
result = []

keys.each do |key|
  part = [key, 0, 0]
  x.each_with_index do |row, index|
    # Detect if the key is in the row. If it is found do:
    # part[index + 1] = value 
  end
  result.push(part)
end

puts result
```

I haven't really fully tested the code but I imagine it could work something like this.